# Resolve AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core' using command-prompt or pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, windows-7

I am struggling because of the error

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'

since quite a long time please refer the output of "import pandas" below. I have searched for this error on the net and searched at many places tried many things but was unable to resolve it. The problem was the solutions provided were more realted to other operating systems like ***Mac*** and ***Linux*** while I am using ***Windows 7 Professional.***

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\IshanL\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "C:\Users\IshanL\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
  File "C:\Users\IshanL\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
  File "C:\Users\IshanL\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Users\IshanL\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Users\IshanL\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 66, in <module>
    import pandas.core.ops as ops
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
```

Please do ask if you need any other details. I will be really gratified if you help me through this. 
Thankyou

P.S if you can suggest a solution which does not use internet using terminal such as in case of "pip install pandas" as the company's network access is restricted. So, I installed all the dependencies of pandas through whl files which are downloadable through the access the company has provided.

Edit: The first time I execute pandas it shows and rest it shows the error shown above

```
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\IshanL\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "C:\Users\IshanL\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
  File "C:\Users\IshanL\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
  File "C:\Users\IshanL\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Users\IshanL\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Users\IshanL\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3978, in <module>
    Series._add_series_or_dataframe_operations()
  File "C:\Users\IshanL\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8891, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
    from pandas.core import window as rwindow
  File "C:\Users\IshanL\PycharmProjects\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 36, in <module>
    import pandas._libs.window as _window
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling pandas ?

Comment: yup I did try to reinstall pandas then I tried to reinstall all of the python set i.e. python.exe and all other packages

Comment: Still it shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda upgrade --all
```

Upgrade your library and restart your notebook.This will do the work.

Comment: As I mentioned above in P.S, I cannot use internet from terminal to upgrade hence this statement will give errors that it cannot connect to the required server